# I'm trying to calculate the total cost when clicking a calculate button

Tags: javascript

I'm new to using JavaScript and stuck on figuring out how to place the value in the input field which I'm planning to also be readonly.

[image: Aiming to place the total cost value after clicking Calculate]

```js
function calculate() {
    var amount = document.getElementById ("ordernum").value;
    amount = parseFloat (amount);
    var price = 450.00;
    var totalprice = amount * price;
    return totalprice;
}
```

```html
<div id="orderform">

    <script src="../../scripts/order_form.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<form action="" method="POST" name="bcpot002" id="bcpot002">
      <div>
        <p>Shallow Copper Red dish form showing distinctive qualities of this traditional reduction fired glaze. Fired to 1300 degrees</p>
        <p>Size: 50cm diameter </br> Glaze Type: Copper Red  </p>
        <label for="unitprice">$450/each</label>
        <select id="ordernum">
            <option>0</option>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>
            <option>6</option>
            <option>7</option>
            <option>8</option>
            <option>9</option>
            <option>10</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="Calculate" onClick="calculate()">
    <br>
    
 <h3>Total Cost</h3>
      <div>
        $<input type="text" id="totalcost" value="0" readonly size="3" />
      </div>
      
      <div>
        <input type="submit" />
        <input value="Reset" type="reset"/>
      </div>
    </form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to select de `totalcost` input from DOM and then place the value on it:

```js
function calculate() {
    var amount = document.getElementById ("ordernum").value;
    amount = parseFloat (amount);
    var price = 450.00;
    var totalprice = amount * price;
    
    // gets dom element
    var totalInput = document.getElementById('totalcost')
    // assign value
    totalInput.value =totalprice 

    // no need to return anything
    //return totalprice;
}
```

```html
<div id="orderform">

    <script src="../../scripts/order_form.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<form action="" method="POST" name="bcpot002" id="bcpot002">
      <div>
        <p>Shallow Copper Red dish form showing distinctive qualities of this traditional reduction fired glaze. Fired to 1300 degrees</p>
        <p>Size: 50cm diameter </br> Glaze Type: Copper Red  </p>
        <label for="unitprice">$450/each</label>
        <select id="ordernum">
            <option>0</option>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>
            <option>6</option>
            <option>7</option>
            <option>8</option>
            <option>9</option>
            <option>10</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="Calculate" onClick="calculate()">
    <br>
    
 <h3>Total Cost</h3>
      <div>
        $<input type="text" id="totalcost" value="0" readonly size="3" />
      </div>
      
      <div>
        <input type="submit" />
        <input value="Reset" type="reset"/>
      </div>
    </form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add that value in the input field by doing this,

`document.getElementById('totalcost').value = totalprice;` after calculating the cost.

```js
function calculate() {
    var amount = document.getElementById ("ordernum").value;
    amount = parseFloat (amount);
    var price = 450.00;
    var totalprice = amount * price;
    console.log(totalprice);
    document.getElementById('totalcost').value = totalprice;
    return totalprice;
}
```

```html
<div id="orderform">

    <script src="../../scripts/order_form.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<form action="" method="POST" name="bcpot002" id="bcpot002">
      <div>
        <p>Shallow Copper Red dish form showing distinctive qualities of this traditional reduction fired glaze. Fired to 1300 degrees</p>
        <p>Size: 50cm diameter </br> Glaze Type: Copper Red  </p>
        <label for="unitprice">$450/each</label>
        <select id="ordernum">
            <option>0</option>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>
            <option>6</option>
            <option>7</option>
            <option>8</option>
            <option>9</option>
            <option>10</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="Calculate" onClick="calculate()">
    <br>
    
 <h3>Total Cost</h3>
      <div>
        $<input type="text" id="totalcost" value="0" size="3" />
      </div>
      
      <div>
        <input type="submit" />
        <input value="Reset" type="reset"/>
      </div>
    </form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set value in #totalcost

please try this code

```
function calculate() {
     var amount = document.getElementById ("ordernum").value;
     amount = parseFloat (amount);
     var price = 450.00;
     var totalprice = amount * price;
     document.getElementById('totalcost').value = totalprice;
}
```

remove **return** from function and set

> document.getElementById('totalcost').value = totalprice;

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change the `calculate` function so that it updates the `totalcost` input element value.

```
function calculate() {
    var amount = document.getElementById ("ordernum").value;
    amount = parseFloat (amount);
    var price = 450.00;
    var totalprice = amount * price;
    
    document.getElementById('totalcost').value = totalprice;
    // return totalprice; // old way, did nothing to UI
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add :
**document.getElementById('totalcost').value = totalprice**
to your JavaScript code.